# Passar valor para variavel em fopen PHP

Tags: php

Opa,

Estou lendo e exibindo o conteúdo de um arquivo .php:

```
$arq="modelo.php";
$abre=fopen($arq,"r+");
$conteudo=fread($abre,filesize($arq));
fclose($abre);

echo $conteudo;
```

Echoa normalmente o html, mas, preciso passar valores para as variaveis do arquivo modelo.php. Ao echoar o conteúdo do arquivo modelo.php, o que é exibido são as tags e não o conteúdo, ou seja:

o echo está me retornando isso:

```
<?php echo $variavel;?>
```

Precisarei disto para a geração automática de páginas simples, o layout completo está no modelo.php, e os valores principais da página são gerados dinamicamente.

Comment: Gerar páginas? Isto não faz sentido, o melhor talvez seria usar `include`, como eu disse fopen não executa scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta sua frase parece confusa, pois você precisa de algo aparentemente simples, mas quer fazer da maneira mais "difícil".

> Precisarei disto para a geração automática de páginas simples, o layout completo está no modelo.php, e os valores principais da página são gerados dinamicamente.

Se quer executar `model.php`, recomendo que use `include` pois então ele irá executar o script chamado, porém não sei bem o que você quer, então segue a resposta...

Como eu disse o `fopen` não executa scripts php, ele lê apenas, o unico caminho que vejo pra alcançar é usar `str_replace` ou `strtr`, por exemplo:

```
$arq="modelo.php";
$abre=fopen($arq, "r+");
$conteudo = fread($abre, filesize($arq));
$conteudo = str_replace('$variavel', $variavel, $conteudo);
fclose($abre);

echo $conteudo;
```

Note que `r+` abre o arquivo pra editar (põe o ponteiro no final) e ler, no seu caso parece que você quer apenas ler, então você pode usar `file_get_contents`, por exemplo:

```
$arq = 'modelo.php';
$conteudo = file_get_contents($arq);
$conteudo = str_replace('$variavel', $variavel, $conteudo);

echo $conteudo;
```

Note que escrever `$var` dentro de `'...'` (apóstrofos) não executa as variáveis.

Um detalhe, se houver alguma variavel tipo `$variavel2` isto pode ser um problema, então talvez seja melhor usar regex, exemplo:

```
$conteudo = preg_replace('#\$(variavel)([^a-z0-9]+)#',
                          '$' . $variavel . '$2', $conteudo);

echo $conteudo;
```

Se tiver mais variaveis você pode usar `strtr`, assim:

```
$arq = 'modelo.php';
$conteudo = file_get_contents($arq);

$trans = array(
            '$varA' => $varA,
            '$varB' => $varB,
            '$varC' => $varC,
            '$varD' => $varD,
            '$varE' => $varE
         );

$conteudo = strtr($conteudo, $trans);
```

Comment: Show, funcionou beleza com o str_replace e o file_get_contents, mas, tenho em media umas 8 variaveis para passar, é possível fazer isso com o preg_replace?

Comment: @sNniffer eu não entendo bem esta sua necessidade, postei um exemplo com `strtr` pra usar varias variaveis, mas peço que explique na sua pergunta o motivo desta necessidade.